# Remove last two characters from a string if it is -C

Tags: php

I need to remove last two characters from a string if it is -C. I'm using the following code for this purpose. Its not producing proper result in some situations.

eg 1: Correct result

```
$str = "215-RTST-C";
echo chop($str,"-C");
```

eg 2: Incorrect Result

```
$str = "210-ADBC-C";
echo chop($str,"-C");
```

Can anyone help me track the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/-C$/', '', $str);
```

would work.

`chop()` aka `rtrim()` is not suitable, because it does not obey character order and has no possibility to limit the number of characters it `chop()`s.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you could use substr. This would do what you need:

```
$str = "215-RTST-C";
if (substr($str, -2) == '-C')
    $str = substr($str, 0, -2);
echo $str;
```

Edit: syck's answer is more efficient, I didn't think of using preg_replace.